# PHP : Calling a models contructor from a controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, constructor, model

I want to create Todolist application using the mvc pattern.

here is my `Todo.php` :

`

```
class Todo {
    public $id;
    public $title;

    public function init($id , $title){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
```

And the `Controller.php`:

```
`<?php

class Controller{

    public function model($model, $params =[]){

        if(file_exists('../app/models/'. $model . '.php')){
            require_once '../app/models/'. $model . '.php';
            return new $model();
        }

        throw new Exception("File ". $model ." does not exist", 1);
    }

    public function view($view, $data = []){
        if(file_exists('../app/views/'. $view .'.php')){
            if($data){
                extract($data);
                unset($data);
                print_r($data);
            }
            var_dump($data);
            require_once '../app/views/'. $view .'.php';
        } else throw new Exception("File ". $view ." does not exist", 1);

    }
}`
```

`home.php` which extends the Controller :

```
`<?php

class home extends Controller {

    public function index(){

        $todos = [
            $this->model('Todo')->init(0 ,'make lunch'),
            $this->model('Todo')->init(1 , 'do homework'),
            $this->model('Todo')->init(2 , 'hang out with Kelly')
        ];

        var_dump($todos);
        $this->view('home/index', $todos);
    }
}
```

now when i run this , the first var_dump($this) in Todo.php outputs :

```
`object(Todo)#4 (2) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["title"]=> string(10) "make lunch" }`
```

while `var_dump($todos)` in home.php outputs : 
    `array(3) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }`

Can anyone explain to me why is it that the array is empty even thow i filled it with Todo object who seem to work fine ( through `var_dump($this)` in `init()` , in `Todo.php` ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the mvc framework you are using but if you need a proper new object you should create wit a new operator eg:  `new objectName() ;`,

in your case somethings like  ..

```
     $todos = [
        new model('Todo')->init(0 ,'make lunch'),
        new model('Todo')->init(1 , 'do homework'),
        new model('Todo')->init(2 , 'hang out with Kelly')
    ];
```

or

```
  $todos = [
        new Todo()->init(0 ,'make lunch'),
        new Todo()->init(1 , 'do homework'),
        new Todo()->init(2 , 'hang out with Kelly')
    ];
```

Comment: It's not a framework actully but what i dont understand is that the object should be created , if `init()` is called ... and yet the array is empty.

Comment: the init method can be called  when  you create an object  if you don't create an object with new operator yoy haven't an object and then you haven't an init function related to the object ..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work when i do that :
`

```
class home extends Controller {

public function index(){

    $todos = [
        $this->model('Todo'),
        $this->model('Todo'),
        $this->model('Todo')
    ];

    $todos[0]->init(0 ,'make lunch');
    $todos[1]->init(1 , 'do homework');
    $todos[2]->init(2 , 'hang out with Kelly');

    $this->view('home/index', $todos);
}
}`
```